# How to populate a Extjs4 grid

Tags: extjs4.1

I'm new to ExtJS4, I have been reading the doc and a book but can't have everything to work how I would like.

I have a form that is submited via AJAX, a JSON response is returned which migh contain none, one or more records. I want to show these records in a new window with a grid component, so the user can select just one record.

I can't make the JSON response to be populated into the grid, for starters,

Where is the JSON response stored?? I have the corresponding success and failure functions.

How I make the grid loads this data into it?

Best Regards,

Comment: You will help others to help you by providing some code. Particularly that of your AJAX call, and the JSON response of the server. If you return a valid JSON, then you can just load it manually into a store that is bound to your grid using [loadRawData](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData)

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something among these lines:

```
...//This is the form onsuccess
succes: function(response) {
    var json = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    var win Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        items: [ {
            xtype:'grid',
            columns:[ ... ],
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data,Store',{
                fields: ['field1', 'field2'],
                data: json })
            }]
        });
    win.show();
}
```

Hope that helps.